# Extrude Curves in Collection with Geonode

Tags: geometry-nodes, svg, stl

I'm working on a decorative piece that will be finally 3D printed. I'm trying to extrude all the shapes (petals of a blossom) that you can see in the picture.

[image: petals]

Ideally their extrusion height would be dependent on their distance to the center of the blossom, but I think I can figure that out later.

Right now I'm struggling to "iterate" over the Curves at all. I managed to extrude a single Curve with this Geonode setup:

[image: geonode-single-curve]

This is where I'm stuck, because I can't figure out how to seperately adjust the Offset Scale of the Extrusion...

[image: stuck]

Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction? Thank you

Gordon pointed out the missing piece for me: Add a Realize Instances Node after Collection Info and then use the ID to modify Offset.

[image: working solution]

This is how the result looks like:

[image: result]

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you just want to give your petals thickness, and curl them, or create an extruded column with the petals as its top feature, in relief? I think we need a little more indication of what you want to wind up with, to be able to suggest approaches.

Comment: If you want each curve to have its own thickness according to the ID, you have to plug a _Realize Instances_ node between the _Collection Info_ and the _Fill Curve_ nodes. But the ID starts with 0, so maybe you should add something to it if the first curve should not be totally flat.

Comment: Thank you guys. 

RobinBetts: you're right. I only want to give each column a "uniform" thickness. I'll try to attach another picture in my original post to make it more clear.

GordonBrinkmann: I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need to realize instances in this case. But anyway, is the result in your last picture the result you wanted?

Comment: You need to realize anyway, and then remesh, if you want to 3D print it (though printer's software could perhaps remesh for you)

Comment: I'm printing with PrusaSlicer and actually it seems pretty happy with the results straight from Blender. 

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes, you'll need it at the end for printing. That was just for the principle: no need to realize in order to make the shape: you can extrude them all as instance (but same size), then scale them up each differently.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, still separated instances after the extrusion. Here is a blend file with the two settings https://blend-exchange.com/b/pwA8gooA/ (that does not matter so much here, just for the principle).

Comment: @lemon Forget what I said, stupid me forgot to click _Separate Children_ :D Anyway, I would have done it differently anyway, I would do this probably with a _Random Value_ instead of using the ID (unless someone told me they had to be increasing in scale in ascending order), and then just using a float with the minimum and maximum value (no need for _Map Range_) and plug it into the _Offset Scale_ of the _Extrude Mesh_ node... if I knew it were for 3D printing and realizing instances would not matter and so I would simply get away with using less nodes.